# Is the phrase 'Going forward' an adverbial phrase? Are there any particular contexts in which it can or cannot be used?

Tags: expressions, adverbials

I recently was asked this question by one of my colleagues,  if this was an adverb or an adjective. While I figure it cannot be an adjective, I presumed it is an adverbial phrase. Would I be right to make that assumption?

Also, what are the rules/conditions/contexts in which one can or cannot use this phrase? Any known colloquial errors that are known?

Comment: It would typically be (part of) an adjunct. Got an example or two?

Comment: Adverbs and adjectives are distinguished by their syntactic affordances. Without a sentence to appear in, it is impossible to tell what this phrase modifies, and therefore what syntactic role it has just by listing the words in it.

Comment: *It was a **going forward** affair.* That's an adjectival use of the phrase. (It sounds a bit odd, but it's syntactical.)